# How to get the tab in which a script has injected?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my Google Chrome extension page I have a content script that injects a script when a particular URL is matched.

I'm trying to get some info about the tab that it's injected into so that I can do some cleanup when the tab gets closed.

To this end, I've tried calling `chrome.tabs.getCurrent()` from within the injected script. However, it returns `undefined`, which is weird because in the [API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getCurrent) it says that `getCurrent()`'s return

> May be undefined if called from a non-tab context (for example: a
>   background page or popup view).

and I'm calling it from within the tab...

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `content script that injects a script` - it means a `<script>` element, right? Which means it's no longer a content script, but just a page script that has no access to chrome.* API. See [Dynamic values in the injected code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879/3959875) section.

Comment: It has access to the `chrome.runtime` API - I'm using it within my injected script. Plus, if it didn't have access to `chrome.tabs` wouldn't I see an error?

Comment: Only `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and it'll work only if the site url is whitelisted in ["externally_connectable"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage).

Comment: @wOxxOm OK, yeah that's true. Perhaps I'm not doing this the right way then. All I want to do is perform some cleanup when the tab with my injected script gets closed. Any suggestions?

Comment: An obvious method would be to use [chrome.tabs.onRemoved](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onRemoved) in the background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, that was what I was thinking. However, I don't want to have to keep polling the browser using `setInterval` and `chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo.url = myUrlMatch, ...)` to find the current tabs with my injected script. Is there no way of getting the tab id from the injected script? That way I could message pass it to the background page and then use `onRemoved` for that id.

Answer (score 2):

In your actual content script ask the background page to give you the tab id.

- content.js

  ```js
  var tabId; // global but not visible to the webpage as it's in an "isolated world"

  chrome.runtime.sendMessage('get-tabId', function(response) {
      tabId = response;

      // inject a page script and pass the tabId
      document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).text = '(' +
          function(tabId) {
              tabId = tabId |0; // coerce to number
              console.log('Injected code got tabId: ', tabId);
          } + ')(' + tabId + ')';

  });
  ```
- background.js

  ```js
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
      if (msg === 'get-tabId') {
          sendResponse(sender.tab.id);
      }
  });
  ```